# Conflict with JS - targets first expander and not the one clicked.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a link that expands to reveal a div when clicked - however, if I have more than one on a page, if I click for eg. the third, it'll open the top one. How do I target the one clicked rather than the first/highest on the page.

```
 $("body").on("click", ".show-hidden", function() {
var $link = $(this);
var $slidingElement = $($link.attr("href"));
if( !$slidingElement.is(':animated') ) {
  $link.toggleClass("shown");
      $slidingElement.slideToggle( 700 );
  }
return false;
```

Comment: Can you post a snippet of your HTML as well?

Answer (score 2):

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/j4wDL/1/

This one works. Can you explain how your layout differs from the mockup I have provided?

```
$(document).on("click", ".show-hidden", function () {
    var $link = $(this);
    var $slidingElement = $($link.attr("href"));

    if (!$slidingElement.is(':animated')) {
        $link.toggleClass("shown");
        $slidingElement.slideToggle(700);
    }
    return false;
});
```

The most likely cause is incorrect hrefs as they would need to include a valid JQuery selector (e.g. `href="#one"`)

Comment: @technophobia: Cute... I started that fiddle back when I commented on the question.